# Nifi validaterecord and convertrecord to validate and convert json record using avroschemaregistry

Tags: apache-nifi

I need help with the understanding and capabilities of `ValidateRecord` and `ConvertRecord` processors in NiFi.

**My requirement**

I have a JSON flow file content having various attributes and few of the fields are mandatory and few are optional and also few fields are timestamp fields and few of double type. There are fields which should have values with in LOV's

I have used `AvroSchemaRegistry` and below schema definition:

```
{
    "namespace": "nifi",
    "name": "test_json",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "sn",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "result",
        "type": {
            "name": "Result",
            "type": "enum",
            "symbols": ["PASS", "FAIL"]
        }
    }, {
        "name": "product",
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 8
    }, {
        "name": "test_station_name",
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 32
    }, {
        "name": "station_id",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "mac_address",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "start_time",
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
    }, {
        "name": "stop_time",
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
    }, {
        "name": "f_p_dip_wave",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }, {
        "name": "f_p_dip_depth",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }, {
        "name": "f_p_dip_height",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }, {
        "name": "radius",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }, {
        "name": "diameter",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }, {
        "name": "gain_cavity_offset_nm",
        "type": ["null", "double"]
    }]
}
```

Field Result should have either PASS or FAIL values and product and test_station_name can have max length restriction on the values and the fields with out default values of "null" are mandatory.

Source side, client application can send any set of attributes in the json and I am trying use validaterecord using jsonreader and jsonwriter to validate the record and then use convertrecord to appropriately convert the json as per the schema.

I can see that NiFi is able to detect the field name and able to perform validation with respect to data type(string, double and timestamp), but not invalidating 
1.records based enum values for result attribute other than PASS or FAIL
2.also not invalidating the records with record length for product and test_station_name fields greater than the max length defined in the schema. 3. Also, even if the JSON does not have the attribute and value for the mandatory filed, validate record is considering "null" for these fields as well.
Rather all the JSON records are getting validated successfully.

**Question**

NiFi `ValidateRecord` and `ConvertRecord` can be used for validating and converting incoming JSON to outgoing json with some of the validation rules explained above. If not, is there an alternate to use groovy script to perform such validation and conversion of incoming json as per the schema.

Please suggest. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) Currently enums from Avro schemas are converted to a string type in NiFi's internal record schema, so that is why any value is passing. There would need to be an enum type in NiFi's record schema which captured the allowable values from the Avro schema.

2) I cannot find anything about maxLength in the Avro specification - https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html  is this a real thing? If it is then NiFi could consider incorporating it.

3) If a field does not have a value then it should be invalid, unless the type of the field is a union with "null" such as "type": ["null", "double"], that would mean the field is not required and is allowed to be null or double.